# how to select ul li in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, design-patterns

i have a ul li in jQuery and i want to select last li from the ul i make 
like

```
<ul>
   <!-- many li here --->
   <li><a id="nqp2" class="apager" href="/2">
        next</a></li>
</ul>
```

how to select last div here without using :last in jQuery

the following thing can be used :>

1. the id starting from char "n" like they always have id starting from "n" and all other not have these char starting from.
2. the last li i want to select always have word next inside them.

are their any way to select li using any way of these two selection pattern

Comment: Could you explain the reason you cannot use :last? There might be workarounds for that problem instead of looking for a different way.

Comment: because their is no way for correctness in dynamic content maybe it's not render by rule.

Answer (score 2):

Using your first method:

```
$('li:has(a[id^="n"])')
```

Using your second method:

```
$('li:contains("next")')
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can use classes and ids to select elements, same as CSS. In this case your last li has a class so:

```
$function (){
    $(".apager")... (rest of your jQuery)
```

It's best to always add a class or id if you'll be selecting it with jQuery/CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery selector: `$('ul li:last-child')`